# Fit text to two pages

Tags: latex

I want to print a missing sheet from the old book. I found text in Internet and measured the page size and margins. After compiling the LaTeX script, it looks good, but doesn't fit to one sheet (two pages). With text size of 9pt text takes up less than two full pages, and with 10pt - more than two pages. How to fit this text to two pages?

Comment: Please add [some code that we can compile](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 2):

Found solution: \linespread{0.93}